# merge two array with different dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have array A and B with the structure:

A:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-08-01
    [1] => 2013-08-02
    [2] => 2013-08-03
    [3] => 2013-08-04 
)
```

and B:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-01
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-02
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-04
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
        )
)
```

The question is I want to combine twi ARRAY (A & B) to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-01
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-02
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-03
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-04
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
        )
)
```

How to merge the both of array?

Comment: Where do these values come from?:
           [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0

Comment: i dont see a difference with array B and the combined array (A and B)

Comment: you need result sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function combine($a, $b) {
    foreach($a as $item_a) {
        foreach($b as $item_b) {
            if(in_array($item_a, $item_b)) {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        $b[] = array(
            $item_a, 0, 0, 0
        );
    }
    usort($b, function($a, $b){return $a[0] > $b[0];});
    return $b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$a = Array
(
    "2013-08-01",
    "2013-08-02",
    "2013-08-03",
    "2013-08-04"
);

$b = Array
(
        Array (
            "2013-08-01",
            2,
            0,
            0
        ),

        Array (
            "2013-08-02",
            0,
            4,
            0
        ),

        Array (
            "2013-08-04",
            0,
            1,
            0
        )
);

foreach ($a as $a_item) {
    $found = FALSE;
    foreach ($b as $b_item) {
        if($b_item[0]==$a_item) {
            $found = TRUE;  
        }
    }

    if(!$found) {
        $b[] = Array (
            $a_item,
            0,
            0,
            0
        );

    }

}

print_r ($b);

?>
```

This should work if you don't have a huge amount of data in the arrays. If you have a large amount of data you should probably do some redesign to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the core dates are in array B, my approach would be to loop through array A and add to array B if a date is found that is not already in array B.

```
foreach ($arrA as $datecheck) {
    $blnAdd = 1;
    foreach ($arrB as $compare) {
        if ($compare[0] == $datecheck) {
            // If found, don't add!
            $blnAdd = 0;
        }
    }
    if ($blnAdd == 1) {
        $arrB[] = array($datecheck, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

// When done, sort array B
// Create helper array for multisort
$arrHelper = array();
foreach ($arrB as $data) {
    $arrHelper = $data[0];
}
// Then, sort array B using values from helper array
array_multisort($arrHelper, $arrB);
```

Then, `$arrB` should contain the values you need.